# Positioning of equation and variable explanation

Tags: equations

I am looking for the following:

[image]

The left part is a formula, middle part is text (e.g. 'for mode') and the right part is a formula again, describing a variable in the left formula. How can I fit everything in one single line?

Comment: Just use `\text{ for mode } n = 0, 1, 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard application of an equation with a `\text` addition (you could also use `\mbox`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  T_n = \frac{4L}{(2n+1)\sqrt{gH}}, \quad \text{for mode $n = 0,1,2,3,\dots$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if 'n = .. ' is a formula? For example n = ax + b

Comment: @André: No difference. Potentially you could use `\text{for mode }` and then type whatever formula you have following it, making sure that the text you write is inside `\text` and that's it.